# Frustumf() function in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using a sample code and not able to understand a function `Frustumf()`.
I want to change `far` argument value in it. my mean I want to see my object smaller then current view.

This is part of `Myrenderer` class in android.

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float aspect = (float)width / height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-aspect, aspect, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 50.0f);
}
```

Comment: I have a codesample specifically aimed at explaining what the parameters of glFrustum mean: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `far` argument has no effect on the size of the object. It only controls the far clipping plane.

As the fancy diagram in @datenwolf's answer shows, the `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` values are measured at the near plane. So it's the relationship of those values with the `near` value that control the field of view, which in turn controls the size of your object.

More precisely, if `bottom` and `top` have the same magnitude, the field of view in the vertical direction is calculated as:

```
fovAngle = 2 * atan(top / near)
```

This means that making the `near` value smaller or making the `top` value larger increases the field of view angle, and making the `near` value larger or the `top` value smaller decreases the field of view.

To make your object smaller using the projection matrix, without changing the clipping planes, you can multiply the first 4 arguments by a factor. E.g.:

```
gl.glFrustumf(-2.0f * aspect, 2.0f * aspect, -2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 50.0f);
```

Since you're increasing the field of view angle, this will also result in a stronger perspective effect. Which may or may not be desirable.

The more standard way of controlling the size of your objects is by modifying the view matrix, while leaving the projection unchanged. For example, to scale by a factor of 2:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glScalef(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture produced by the program https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum

The grid is in the XY plane with Z=0, the labeled measure arrows depict the parameters for the frustum.

[image: Frustum and a Scene]